# How to show confirmation pop up when changing page in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, popup

I am landing on the first page of DataTable, make some changes. 
Then I move to the second page.

Actually, confirmation popup is shown but it navigate to the second page.

Expected: confirm pop is shown but it still landing on the first.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#dataTable-id').on( 'page.dt', function (event) {            
if( change ){ 
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Confirmation",
        message : "Discard changes?",
        buttons :{
            main: {
                label : "Leave",
                className : "btn-primary",
                callback: function (){
                    // To avoid broking page/length controller
                    // move to other pages
                    return true; // cancel draw
                }
            },
            cancel: {
                label : "Stay",
                className : "btn-default",
                callback : function() {
                    // stay at current page.
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        },onEscape: function () {return true;}
    });

}
```

});

How to show confirmation popup before page change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page.dt event is only informational, it can not be canceled.

You can workaround that restriction by writing a custom preDrawCallback like discussed here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25507

EDIT: You have to cancel the redraw generally and do the paging manually in the bootbox callback (as it does not work as a real modal dialog like the native javascript confirm()). I modified the above example to incorporate a bootbox confirm dialog on paging: https://jsfiddle.net/bk4nvds5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var pageLen = 10;

    var originalPage = 0;
    var originalPageLen = pageLen;
    var gotoPage = 0;
    var gotoPageLen = originalPageLen;
    var fromBootbox = false;

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pageLength": pageLen,
        "preDrawCallback": function (settings) {

            if(table){ // ignore first draw

                if (!fromBootbox) {
                    // To avoid broking page/length controller, we have to reset the paging information
                    gotoPage = settings._iDisplayStart;
                    gotoPageLen = settings._iDisplayLength;                
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                      console.log("goto page" + gotoPage + " (result: " + result + ")");
                                        if (result) {
                        fromBootbox = true;
                        table.page.len(gotoPageLen);
                        table.page(gotoPage / gotoPageLen).draw(false);
                        fromBootbox = false;
                      }
                                        });
                    settings._iDisplayStart = originalPage;
                    settings._iDisplayLength = originalPageLen;
                    $('[name="example_length"]').val(originalPageLen);

                    return false; // cancel draw

                }else{
                    originalPage = settings._iDisplayStart;
                    originalPageLen = settings._iDisplayLength;                
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I have read this http://jsfiddle.net/ktbf8day/19/, It uses browser confirm popup confirm("Are you sure?"). It is ok. But I want to change to confirmation popup bootbox (mean that custom popup), It does not work correctly

Comment: I added a sample imlementation to the referenced example.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, in the originally referenced example, the confirmation dialog was made with the javascript native confirm() method. confirm() is a synchronous call, so the execution stops until the dialog is dismissed (with either cancel or ok). After that, execution continues and the preDrawCallback() can be aborted depending on the result of the confirm() call.

The Bootbox confirm dialog, otoh, works asynchronous. The execution continues while the dialog is shown, so you have to abort the preDrawCallback() unconditionally, and redo the paging in the resulting event of the Bootbox dialog.

Comment: Thank for your explanation. I got your idea and knew how to native confirm and bootbox work. It is useful for me. Hope that it also useful for someone who looking for.

Comment: However, I tried with bootbox dialog, but it does not work correctly

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle a provided above? It does work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/bk4nvds5/

Comment: Thank you, I am using your demo. It is so good. But I tried with bootbox.dialog, it is not correcly

Comment: no, It uses bootbox.confirm not bootbox.dialog. May be you give wrong link ?

Comment: Ah, I understand. But bootbox.confirm is ony a special case of bootbox.dialog. I updated my fiddle to use your dialog from the question: https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/bk4nvds5/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123197/discussion-between-jerry-and-nicolai-ehemann).